# Query for SUM values on multiple columns, then substract and compare results

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-formula

I have the following scenario: 
A Google Sheet to collect daily Cash Flow on two shifts (Morning and Afternoon), starting each shift with money on hand (cash) and money on bank account (to pay bills and make transfers as necessary).
The circuit works by recording money IN or money OUT and using the direction of the flow as a basic selector, in order to determine by adding and substracting, how much money came in, and how much came out.

[image]

I've been testing with long `QUERY` formulae to try to come out with results, but so far, I managed to only filter by means of `SUM(X)`. However, I been trying after reading all documentation about Query Formula, to select and sum every income for every shift within the day, do the math, compare with the starting cash, and determine how much money by means of payment, date and shift came in or out.

This is the Query formula for the collected items:

```
=QUERY(A1:Q,"SELECT A,B, SUM(G), SUM(H), SUM(I), SUM(J), SUM(K) WHERE E='Collected' AND L='Cash' GROUP BY A,B LABEL SUM(G)'Rentals Collected' ",2)
```

And this is the Query formula for the paid items:

```
=QUERY(A1:Q,"SELECT A,B, SUM(G), SUM(H), SUM(I), SUM(J), SUM(K) WHERE E='Paid' AND L='Cash' GROUP BY A,B LABEL SUM(G)'Rentals Paid' ",2)
```

I've also used this Query formula for displaying money available on hand at the start of each shift, for each day.

```
=QUERY(A:Q, "SELECT A,B,C,D WHERE C IS NOT NULL", 2)
```

[image]

Any ideas?

Here's a [Dummy Sheet that recreates the scenario](http://goo.gl/jCuUD9).

Comment: Would something like `=QUERY(A1:Q32,"SELECT A,B, SUM(G)+ SUM(H)+ SUM(I)+ SUM(J)+ SUM(K), SUM(O) GROUP BY A,B label SUM(G)+ SUM(H)+ SUM(I)+ SUM(J)+ SUM(K) 'income', SUM(O) 'expendature' ",2)` help?

Comment: @Salixalba: Thanks for your response! I tried your suggestion, but it considers column 'O' as only "expenditures" and it is recording "income" as well. I also tried to filter every in/out by means of a `Query X,Y,Z Where W='Collected', but it didn't work.

Comment: If column O can have negative or positive values you can use

Comment: Could you make two new columns, one for the income values in O and one for the expendature values. You could fill these using an IF function.

Comment: @Salixalba: Thanks for your recommendation. The use of negative in expenditures values was also suggested by Jacob Jan Tuinstra. By the way, how do you suggest I perform the operation using an IF function?

Comment: `IF(E5='Collected', O5, 0)` and replicate down. You need to do this outside of `QUERY` and the query api has a very limited set of functions.

Comment: @Salixalba: Thanks again for the input! I'll try to make it work with your suggestion and let you know. Best regards